# Access media_url from twitter API

Tags: php, arrays, twitter

I cannot access the media_url from the twitter API. I know it is in the media array, and I believe that the media array is in an entity array. I just can't get the syntax right. I have tried making a similar array to the user array, but that doesn't work. I have also tried making an entity array like the user array, but the array comes back empty.

```html
  <?php
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');

  /** Set access tokens here - see: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/ **/
  $settings = array(
      'oauth_access_token' => "XXX-XXXXXXXX",
      'oauth_access_token_secret' => "XXXXXXXX",
      'consumer_key' => "XXXXX",
      'consumer_secret' => "XXXX"
  );

  /** URL for REST request, see: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/ **/
  $url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/blocks/create.json';
  $requestMethod = 'GET';

  /** POST fields required by the URL above. See relevant docs as above **/
  $postfields = array(
      'screen_name' => 'usernameToBlock',
      'skip_status' => '1'
  );

  /** Perform a POST request and echo the response
e response **/
  /** Note: Set the GET field BEFORE calling buildOauth(); **/
  $url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
  $getfield = '?q=%23blacklivesmatter';
  $requestMethod = 'GET';
  $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);


  $tweetData = json_decode($twitter->setGetField($getfield)
                ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
                ->performRequest(),$assoc = TRUE);

  echo $tweetData;


  foreach($tweetData['statuses'] as $items)
      {

        $userArray = $items['user'];
        $entitiesArray = $items['entities'];
        $mediaArray = $entitiesArray['media'];
        $date = new DateTime( $items->created_at );


        echo "<div class='tweet-div'><div class='float-left twitpic'><a target='_blank' href='http://www.twitter.com/" . $userArray['screen_name'] . "'><img class='twitter-pic' target='_blank' src='" . $userArray['profile_image_url'] . "'></a></div>";
        echo "<a target='_blank' href='http://www.twitter.com/" . $userArray['screen_name'] . "'><span class='name bold'>" . $userArray['name'] . "</span>   </br><span class='handle'>@" . $userArray['screen_name'] . "</span></a>  <span class='font-small'>&sdot; ";
        echo $date->format( 'M jS' ) . "</span></br>";
        echo $items['text'] . "</br></br>";
        echo "<img target='_blank' src='http://" . $mediaArray['media_url'] . "'></br></br>";
        echo $mediaArray['media_url'] . "";
        echo "<span class='border'></span></div>";


        }



  echo $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
               ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
               ->performRequest();

  ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you load tweets with query, get media_url from this path

```
$mm1= $tweetData['statuses']["0"]['entities']['media']['0']['media_url'];
echo $mm1;
```

and you will have correct data for (first)image attached to the tweet. If you have more images you can increment that number ['0'] and find more.

I had to waste hours before I could get proper image to display along with tweet status(text)
I also saw that some media do not have ['0'] but direct 'media_url' after 'media'. My method may not be perfect yet to access all media but my purpose was solved.
Best luck